# Mass upsert in Laravel (Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to mass upsert (Insert or Update if exists) records in Laravel (MySQL database) ?

Say I have a table with:

```
[id:1 value:4]
[id:2 value:5]
```

I want to perform:

```
Model::massupsert([
  [id:1 value:100],
  [id:3 value:20]
]);
```

And the table afterwards to be:

```
[id:1 value:100]
[id:2 value:5]
[id:3 value:20]
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql database.

Comment: Laravel has no native upsert support (yet). You can use this package: https://github.com/yadakhov/insert-on-duplicate-key

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as the solution..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now (Oct 6, 2020), Laravel(v8.10.0) has native `upsert` support. https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/34698

```
Model::upsert([
    ['id' => 1, 'value' => 100],
    ['id' => 3, 'value' => 20],
], 'id');
```

Comment: Awesome, but it looks like Laravel just create multiple `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements, which is really really slow when your array is larger. If performance is important, then using **one** raw statement might be much faster

Comment: Be aware, if you're using this on MySQL, `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` increments the the auto increment value. So, you could have gaps in your IDs using this. Postgres *may* do this as well and you should check how other DB engines handle this. upsert would be *GREAT* if your unique key were a UUID.

Answer (score 6):

Laravel has no native UPSERT support.

I've created a package for this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-upsert

```php
Model::upsert([
    ['id' => 1, 'value' => 100],
    ['id' => 3, 'value' => 20],
], 'id', ['value']);
```

Comment: use this and it worked perfectly, just one thing tho.. from the instructions, you have to add use \Staudenmeir\LaravelUpsert\Eloquent\HasUpsertQueries; to the model class;

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use `updateOrCreate()` method. Quoting from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment):

> You may also come across situations where you want to update an existing model or create a new model if none exists. Laravel provides an updateOrCreate method to do this in one step.

```php
$data = collect([
    ['id' => 1, 'value' => 100],
    ['id' => 3, 'value' => 20]
]);

$data->each(function ($item) {
    Model::updateOrCreate([
        ['id' => $item['id']],
        ['value' => $item['value']]
    ]);
});
```

**Note:** if you have to process many records at once this method could lead to slow processing, as you are creating/updating one model at a time into the database.

#### Update #1: Reduce queries

You could then reduce a bit the number of queries with `firstOrNew`, as you just bulk insert the new records into the database, but you currently have to manually update the already existing records one at a time:

```php
$data = collect([
    ['id' => 1, 'value' => 100],
    ['id' => 3, 'value' => 20]
]);

$models = $data->map(function ($attributes) {
    $model = Model::firstOrCreate([
        ['id' => $attributes['id']],
        ['value' => $attributes['value']]
    ]);

    if (! $model->exists) {
        $model->fill($attributes);
    }

    return $model;
});

list($saved, $unsaved) = $models->partition(function ($model) {
    return $model->exists;
});

Model::insert($unsaved);
$saved->each->update();
```

Currently to do that with a single query you have to use a package as suggested by *Jonas Staudenmeir* in comments.

Comment: Thanks you but I am looking for a solution that results in 1 SQL query and not multiple calls (for better performance)

Comment: @Yaron Have you find any better solution for decrease the size of query?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 8 now has an upsert function which I am using in my last project. I'm quite enjoying it!

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#update-statements

The upsert method will insert records that do not exist and update the records that already exist with new values that you may specify. The method's first argument consists of the values to insert or update, while the second argument lists the column(s) that uniquely identify records within the associated table. The method's third and final argument is an array of columns that should be updated if a matching record already exists in the database:

```
DB::table('flights')->upsert([
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
    ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
], ['departure', 'destination'], ['price']);
```

Comment: Just a heads-up. As mentioned in docs -->  All databases except SQL Server require the columns in the second argument of the upsert method to have a "primary" or "unique" index. In addition, the MySQL database driver ignores the second argument of the upsert method and always uses the "primary" and "unique" indexes of the table to detect existing records.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to upsert then you should use:

```
YourModel::query()->upsert([
    ["id" => 1, "value" => 100],
    ["id" => 3, "value" => 20],
]);
```

If you want to upsert and get upserted rows back or if you use eloquent's events (such as created/creating/saving/saved/etc) then you can use the library: https://github.com/lapaliv/laravel-bulk-upsert. For example:

```
$upsertedRows = YourModel::query()
    ->bulk()
    ->uniqueBy(['id']) // unique field
    ->upsertAndReturn([
        ["id" => 1, "value" => 100],
        ["id" => 3, "value" => 20],
    ]);
```

This library works a little bit slowly than `YourModel::query()->upsert()`, but it gives you some additional functional.

In my opinion, it's better to use the both ways. You just need to know when it's better to use one and when the other.